# What controls the sortDirection arrow in lightning-datatable?

Tags: lightning-datatable, sort

I have a lightning-datatable (lwc) that has a number of columns that are sortable. I'm tracking the sort direction of each column with a separate variable.

The sorting works great, including sortDirection -- *except that* the sort arrow on every column always points up -- even if the actual sort is DESC.

I can't figure out how to change that. What is the value that datatable uses to determine which arrow to display?

Here's my markup:

```
       <lightning-datatable
            key-field="id"
            data={responses}
            columns={columns}
            onsave={handleSave}
            draft-values={draftValues}
            onsort={handleSort}
            sorted-by={sortedBy}
            sorted-direction={sortedDirection}
            onrowselection={handleRowSelected}
            onrowaction={handleRowAction}
            show-row-number-column
            enable-infinite-loading
            onloadmore={handleLoadMore}>
        </lightning-datatable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LWC (and Aura, Lightning, JavaScript, etc) is case sensitive. The allowed values are `asc` and `desc`. If you use the correct values, the arrows should appear in the correct direction.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have put DESC in my question. I do, in fact, have `asc` and `desc` in my code -- lower case. But there are arrows over several columns, and only one sortDirection parameter in the markup. How does it track direction for each column?

Comment: @PatMcClellan__c oh. Did you set a sort field as well? You need both for it to behave correctly.

Comment: Just added my markup above. Yes, included sorted-by and sorted-direction. Oh... I think that might be the issue though. I'm assigning this.sortedBy the fieldName__c and using that in my server call. But the columns don't have the __c. I'll update after I check that.

Comment: yep, that was it. I was multipurposing my {sortedBy} variable. I created a new var orderBy, leaving sortedBy tied to the columnName. That fixed it. Thanks.